# Loop across url with static tokens with Oauth

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting, curl

I need to write a loop where I need to pass a "token" (which is fixed) and a variable (`i`) in the url. Is there any way I can achieve that? I wrote the following code but it is not working. If I put double quotes around the entire url it doesn't work

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do 
    curl -O "https://api.mysite.com/info?&access_token=xyx"&page=i
done
```

Comment: Please explain a bit better what you are trying to obtain. Maybe with examples. Posting the errors also helps. One sure mistake in your command is that you have to use `$i` after `page=`.

Answer (score 0):

The character `&` is special syntax in the shell, so what you've written runs the `curl` command in the background and runs the command `page=i` in the foreground. You need to put it inside the quotes.

To refer to the value of a variable, put a `$` before it. A variable substitution looks like this: `$i` — and it must be inside double quotes, not inside single quotes. You can also leave variable substitutions unquoted, but that [further expands the value of the variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) so don't do it until you understand when it's safe — only use `$i` inside double quotes.

```
for ((i=1; i<=100; i++)); do 
    curl -O "https://api.mysite.com/info?access_token=xyx&page=$i"
done
```